# Visual studio does not recognise RelativeSource Self in xaml in Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, binding, relativesource

I read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) that the following example should work in a Xamarin project.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
       HeightRequest="30" 
       WidthRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HeightRequest}">
</Label>
```

But my visual studio (up to date v2019) marks the 'RelativeSource Self' part in red and gives me the following compile errors:

- Error XLS0414 The type 'RelativeSource' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
- Error Position 20:79. Type RelativeSource not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Weirdly enough, when opening the sample project found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/databindingdemos/), visual studio also shows 'RelativeSource Self' in red but does compile.

I have not read anywhere that I need to include an assembly for this and VisualStudio and resharper don't give me include hints.

OK.. UPDATE .. I found out that I needed to upgrade my xamarin.forms references from 4.1 to 4.4 to get rid of the compile warnings.

But I find it odd that VisualStudio keeps marking the statement 'RelativeSource Self' in red.

Comment: If the compiler builds successfully, it would be no problem , try to restart your pc and ide to check if error persists.

Comment: rebooting does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Xamarin Forms 4.4.0.991864 solved the issue in my place!

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
Version 16.5.4